# How is an undefined variable initialized/interpreted by PHP?

Tags: php, variables, initialization

Well, I have to remove warnings of an existing PHP 5.4 script and I am not sure how to handle the following prob correctly.

I got a source code like

```
if ($start_id_minus >= 0)
{
    $tmp_link = $link."&id=$start_id_minus";
    $tmp_html_previous .= "<a href='$tmp_link'><<&nbsp;previous</a>&nbsp;";
}
```

Which results in a notice like `"Notice: Undefined variable: $tmp_html_previous in <5 lines below>"`

So what I have to do is to initialize the variable before this "if".
In this case it is obvious that $tmp_html_previous is a string, so what I could do is:

```
$tmp_html_previous = '';
```

But I got many similiar case where the "type" of the variable is not obvious to me. So how do I initialize these variables correctly? With NULL? With 0? With ''? Not at all: var $tmp;?

Comment: You initialize it with required default value. It can be `null`, `''`, `0` or whatever you need

Comment: First, why use

    `$tmp_link = $link."&id=$start_id_minus";`

if $link isn't defined.

Second, how could you not know which type to initialize a variable to? If your code is that unclear, you should really consider refactoring.

Comment: The prob is that I do not know the expected default value.

Comment: This is not my code. This is my problem. And no, there is nobody I could ask.

Comment: Sounds like it's your code now, and if you can't read it well enough to determine the right type for a variable, you've got worse problems than these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is the obvious initial value for any variables you're going to do mathematical operations on.
`true` or `false` is the obvious initial value for "boolean variables".
`null` is a good initial value for anything else.

Comment: consider this line _But I got many similar case where the "type" of the variable is not obvious to me_

Comment: So `null` it is then. There's no absolute answer for this, especially without more concrete examples; only guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since it looks as if you're building a string, you could use:

```
$tmp_html_previous = '';
```

Or:

```
$tmp_html_previous = NULL;
```

If $tmp_html_previous were a boolean value, you could set the default as true or false.

```
$tmp_html_previous = false;
```

If you're doing calculations:

```
$tmp_html_previous = 0;
```

Basically, it all depends on the logic of your application.

Answer (score -1):

With whatever you want, the type will change automatically as PHP is not strongly typed.

Answer (score -1):

Just whatever to initialize; if concerned about appending strings that do it `string`:

`$tmp = isset($tmp) ? $tmp : '';`

However, `null` is always the obvious solution.

Comment: The point is to initialize to a good known value at a defined point so you don't need `isset`.

Comment: @deceze so what's the harm in checking if the value already exists?

Comment: You can't check every single time you want to use the variable. That's just madness and code clutter. Therefore you want to initialize the variable so you *know* it exists. You should only use `isset` for variables you really have no control over.